# No effects with nivoSlider

Tags: javascript, slider, nivo-slider

Nivo slider is working fine but does not do any effects.

Comment: It would be nice if you supplied some kind of code in the question.

Comment: @Dynamic, he had given the URL itself!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Which means we have to find the code ourselves. More work for us :P

Comment: @Dynamic Are you serious? It is Css/html/javascript question, and I gave you link, isn't it better if you check for yourself rather then copy here? Please guys think first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a z-index problem, in nivo-slider.css:18

```
.nivoSlider img {
...
    z-index: 50;
}
```

This is covering up the animation, remove it and you'll see the transitions.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you need to give the `<script>` tags inside `<head>` tag.

```
<!-- Javascripts -->
<script src="http://ipmgroup.org/wp-content/themes/ipmgroup/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ipmgroup.org/wp-content/themes/ipmgroup/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>    
<script src="http://ipmgroup.org/wp-content/themes/ipmgroup/scripts/ipm.main.js"></script>
```

Try changing it and check out. Finally, the CSS Part:

```
// Need more z-index from default
//Line Number 45!
.nivo-slice {z-index: 100;}
//Line Number 18!
.nivoSlider img {z-index: 10;}
```

Try this and it works! :)